# Extending ResourceManagerStringLocalizer functionality

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am fairly new to .net core and I want to implement localization in my application. The built in [ResourceManagerStringLocalizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.localization.resourcemanagerstringlocalizer?view=aspnetcore-3.0) service satisfies almost all my requirements and works great out of the box, but I want to add some custom functionality to it, without copy pasting all of the class' code and adding some to it in my own localizer. Currently I have tried deriving from the class in my own Localizer and injecting that as my IStringLocalizer:

```
services.AddTransient<IStringLocalizer<MyApp.SharedResource>, MyLocalizer<MyApp.SharedResource>>();
```

...

```
public class MyLocalizer<T> : ResourceManagerStringLocalizer, IStringLocalizer<T> {
    public MyLocalizer(ResourceManager resourceManager, IResourceStringProvider resourceStringProvider, string baseName, IResourceNamesCache resourceNamesCache, ILogger logger) : base(resourceManager, resourceStringProvider, baseName, resourceNamesCache, logger) {
    }

    public override LocalizedString this[string name] {
        get {
            //do some custom functionality

            return base[name];
        }
    }

    public override LocalizedString this[string name, params object[] arguments] {
        get {
            //do some custom functionality

            return base[name, arguments];
        }
    }
}
```

But this gives the following exception when trying to use it:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Resources.ResourceManager' while attempting to activate 'MyApp.Services.MyLocalizer`1[MyApp.SharedResource]'.'
```

My question is, what's the best way to this? And whats best practice for doing things like this? I feel like this sort of stuff may come up more often in the future of this application and all help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to override the built-in localizer, just implement your custom one:

```cs
public class MyLocalizer
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer _localizer;
    public MyLocalizer(IStringLocalizerFactory factory)
    {
        var type = typeof(MyResourceType);
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
        _localizer = factory.Create("MyResourceType", assemblyName.Name);
    }

    public LocalizedString this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            // ...

            return _localizer[name];
        }
    }

    public LocalizedString this[string name, params object[] arguments]
    {
        get
        {
            // ...

            return _localizer[name, arguments];
        }
    }

}
```

Then you can simple inject it to the views:

```html
@inject MyLocalizer _loc;

<h1>@_loc["Hellow"]</h1>
```

or to the backend:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyLocalizer _loc;
    public HomeController(MyLocalizer loc)
    {
        _loc = loc;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var msg = _loc["Welcome"];
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, May I ask you what 'MyResourceType' should be, I am also new to .net core and don't see clearly? thanks